# Calculate cumulative values for each row based on another index column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

Given a table:

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.6 |
| 2 | 7.6 |
| 3 | 5.6 |
| 4 | 6.1 |

I would like to calculate a cumulative sum for each row, where the sum is calculated by summing the *Value* column where indices are equal or larger than the *Index* value for current row, so that:

| Index | Value | Value_Cum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.6 | 21.9 |
| 2 | 7.6 | 19.3 |
| 3 | 5.6 | 11.7 |
| 4 | 6.1 | 6.1 |

using Power Query M language in Excel.
To illustrate the logic better, the *Value_Cum* column was calculated, using Excel Table syntax, with the following formula:
`=SUM(FILTER([Value];[Index]>=[@Index]))`

**Edit:**

In response to @horseyride proposed solution, it has to also work for cases where there are multiple identical values of *Index* as well as when the *Index* is not sorted.
Additonal example, where the source table with the cumulative value is as follows:

| Index | Value | Value_Cum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2.3 | 26.1 |
| 2 | 9.9 | 56.7 |
| 6 | 3 | 29.1 |
| 3 | 2.5 | 46.8 |
| 10 | 9.2 | 23.8 |
| 10 | 5.9 | 23.8 |
| 3 | 8 | 46.8 |
| 4 | 7.2 | 36.3 |
| 10 | 8.7 | 23.8 |

and if I create a *Custom* column with power query using the formula:
`= Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Custom", each List.Sum(List.RemoveFirstN(Source[Value],[Value]-1)))`
it results in errors, see the results (empty values are errors):

| Index | Value | Value_Cum | Custom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 9.9 | 56.7 |  |
| 3 | 8 | 46.8 | 15.9 |
| 3 | 2.5 | 46.8 |  |
| 4 | 7.2 | 36.3 |  |
| 6 | 3 | 29.1 | 44.5 |
| 7 | 2.3 | 26.1 |  |
| 10 | 8.7 | 23.8 |  |
| 10 | 9.2 | 23.8 |  |
| 10 | 5.9 | 23.8 |  |

Comment: Some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112231/how-to-achieve-running-total-with-power-query Also consider if you do not have too many more steps in your query, you could just add the formula column to the table after loading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
let a = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (x)=> 
x[Index] >= [Index]), 
b = List.Sum(a[Value]) 

in b
```

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, Add column .. custom column ... with formula:

```
= List.Sum(List.RemoveFirstN(Source[Value],[Index]-1))
```

[image]

potentially for large data sets, buffer the column first

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
stored = List.Buffer(Source[Value]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Cumulative", each List.Sum(List.RemoveFirstN(stored,[Index]-1)))
in #"Added Custom"
```

EDIT

alternate for revised needs

```
let Source = #table(type table [Index = nullable Int64.Type, Value = nullable number], {{7,2.3},{2,9.9},{6,3},{3,2.5},{10,9.2},{10,5.9},{3,8}, {4,7.2},{10,8.7}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Index"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([Value]), type nullable number}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Index", Order.Descending}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Sum", each [Value]+(List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Sorted Rows"[Value],List.PositionOf(#"Sorted Rows"[Index],[Index])))??0)),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each #"Added Custom"[Sum]{List.PositionOf(#"Added Custom"[Index],[Index])})
in #"Added Custom2"
```

Comment: I included and Edit to the original post with additional case where this solution does not work

Comment: If your sample data has changed but the solution worked for your original, you should really mark as solved and ask a new question. In this case, I have provided an answer but @horseyride should get credit for the initial correct response. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

*(The accepted answer is probably best in most cases but for large tables or any other reason you might need something that performs better...)*

Instead of scanning the table per row in the table, you can calculate subtotals by scanning through the table **once**, like so:

```ml
let
  Source = #table(
    type table [Index = nullable Int64.Type, Value = nullable number],
    {
      {7 , 2.3},
      {2 , 9.9},
      {6 , 3  },
      {3 , 2.5},
      {10, 9.2},
      {10, 5.9},
      {3 , 8  },
      {4 , 7.2},
      {10, 8.7}
    }
  ),
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
    Source,
    {"Index"},
    {{"Values", each [Value], type list}}
  ),
  #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(
    #"Grouped Rows",
    {{"Index", Order.Descending}}
  ),
  SubtotalPerIndex = List.Accumulate(
    Table.ToRecords(#"Sorted Rows"),
    [Subtotal = 0],
    (state, _) => let
      NewSubtotal = state[Subtotal] + List.Sum([Values])
    in
      state & Record.AddField(
        [Subtotal = NewSubtotal],
        Text.From([Index]),
        NewSubtotal
      )
  ),
  #"Added Value_Cum" = Table.AddColumn(
    Source,
    "Value_Cum",
    each Record.Field(
      SubtotalPerIndex,
      Text.From([Index])
    ),
    type number
  )
in
  #"Added Value_Cum"
```