# How to use a column value as a variable for a calculated column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have the **Grades** table:

| Grade |
| --- |
| 88 |
| 91 |
| 97 |
| 92 |
| 84 |

and the **PassCount** table:

| Value |
| --- |
| 80 |
| 85 |
| 90 |
| 95 |

I would like to add a calculated column to **PassCount**, called "Count", which would be the count of how many rows from the Grades table have a Grade which exceeds the value specified in **PassCount**'s Value column.

For example, the first row of PassCount has a Value of 80, so the Count should count how many rows have a Grade higher than 80. All 5 are, so the Count should be 5 for the first row.

The expected result would be a **PassCount** table looking like this:

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 80 | 5 |
| 85 | 4 |
| 90 | 3 |
| 95 | 1 |

The issue is that I can not find the syntax to achieve this. If I try:

```
Count = Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(Grades, each [Grade] > [PassValue]))
```

Then PassValue can't be found.

If I try:

```
Count = Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(Grades, each Grades[Grade] > PassCount[PassValue]))
```

Then a cyclic reference is encountered.

I've also tried making measures and intermediate queries, but run into similar problems. I can't figure out how to use a table of values as variable values for a query/calculation.

Comment: Your question is confusing. It reads like your doing this in Dax but then provide Powerquery code. Which is it?

Comment: Perhaps that is part of the issue. I'd be happy implementing either, but haven't been able to get the M language to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate cumulative values for each row based on another index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759213/calculate-cumulative-values-for-each-row-based-on-another-index-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
Table.RowCount( Table.SelectRows(Grades, (x)=>  x[Grade] > [Value]))
```